# Why can't I 'modify' other class' String array?

Tags: java

I have two classes in my App, let's call it A and B. The A class uses B classes' String array in a method which is supposed to make that array one bigger and assign a certain value to the last index.

My problem is that it seems like it doesn't make the array larger by a 1, even though it worked fine when the class B was declared as static and variables too.

The way I referenced B's String array:

```
public class classA {

void myMethod() {
classB instance = new classB();
instance.array1 = Arrays.copyOf(instance.array1, instance.array1.length +1);
instance.array1[(instance.array1.length -1)] = someValue;} }

class classB{
String[] array1 = new String[0];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

My actual snippet:

```
void save() {
    try {
        QAData qaObject = new QAData();
        File file = new File("path");
        boolean fileIsOk = file.isFile() && !(tf3.getText().equals("")) && !(file.isDirectory());
        if (fileIsOk) {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            qaObject.question = Arrays.copyOf(qaObject.question, qaObject.question.length + 1);
            qaObject.question[(qaObject.question.length - 1)] = tf1.getText();
            qaObject.answer = Arrays.copyOf(qaObject.answer, qaObject.answer.length + 1);
            System.out.println(qaObject.question.length );
            qaObject.answer[(qaObject.answer.length - 1)] = tf2.getText();
            oos.writeObject(qaObject.question);
            oos.writeObject(qaObject.answer);}

            for (int i = 0; i < qaObject.question.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("question is: " + qaObject.question[i]);
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < qaObject.answer.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(("answer is: " + qaObject.answer[i]));
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O exception during the save");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println("The object you are trying to save has the null value");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("error!!!!!");
    }
    finally {
            if (oos != null) {
                try{
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IO Exception!");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class QAData implements Serializable {
    String[] question = new String[0];
    String[] answer = new String[0];
}
```

Comment: What if Arrays.copyOf(... +2) instead of `+1`?

Comment: @GenoChen I just tried and it still won't make it larger :(

Comment: Use a debugger to see what happened internally?

Comment: @GenoChen Sadly, I would but I don't know how to, it's my first programming language :(

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? It works fine for me - how are you trying to verify whether it "works"?

Comment: How do you check the result of this? Or in other words, how do you come to the conclusion that the array isn't modified? The code as shown only performs modification, it doesn't check anything.

Comment: @Krease I did by printing the length of the array and also a for loop and it won't increase the size if the classB and String arrays are not static

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I used System.out.println(instance.array1.length); and a for loop : for (int i = 0; i < instance.array1.length; i++) { System.out.println( instance.array1[i];}

Comment: Please edit the question to show a self-contained example including your testing code

Comment: That sounds like you are using a different instance of `classB` to test than the one you modified.

Comment: So... if it didn't work, you'd be getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` when executing this: `qaObject.question[(qaObject.question.length - 1)]` - are you getting that exception?

Comment: @Krease I'm not, so is there a problem with my testing methods?

Comment: @Krease I'm not, here is an output I get : 

1
question is: a
answer is: a

1
question is: 3
answer is: 3

Comment: Your test is just outputting the array contents. From what I can see, you've successfully increased array size from 0 to 1.  For easy comparision, do an output of the array contents before you modify them, and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Your code is not a [mcve], so it is hard to verify. The most common cause seems to be `fileIsOk` being `false`. A reduced example works as expected: https://ideone.com/oZ3heS

Comment: @Krease the thing is the output should be like this if it increases: 2 question is a question is 3 answer is a answer is 3

Comment: The code as shown will only ever contain 0 or 1 questions: you are creating a **new** `QAData` every time so at most 1 question will get added; you are not reading the old set of answers from file.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel this was the problem! I moved the QAData qaObject = new QAData(); somewhere else and now it works fine! Thank you so so much you literally saved me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are ultimately trying to achieve. My engineer's brain says there is a simpler way to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do.

The biggest problem I can see is that you're using a bare `Array`. Use an `ArrayList` instead. Using an `ArrayList`, you can have all the resizing and such done for you.

If you're committed to using an `Array`, at least provide a public method in `classB` that handles all the heavy lifting of resizing the array and such. Declare it something like this:

```
public void addOneToEnd( String someValue )
```

Classes should handle their own data, and not let outside classes mess with it. You should use the method approach even if you go with an `ArrayList` (which you really should).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me. Unless I'm missing something:

```
public class Tester {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    classA a = new classA();
    a.myMethod();
  }
}
class classA {

  void myMethod() {
    classB instance = new classB();
    instance.array1 = Arrays.copyOf(instance.array1, instance.array1.length + 1);
    instance.array1[(instance.array1.length - 1)] = "someValue";
    System.out.println(instance.array1[(instance.array1.length -1)]);
  }
}

class classB {
  String[] array1 = new String[0];
}
```

It prints `someValue` for me. Initial length of array was 0 which now is 1.

If this line: `instance.array1[(instance.array1.length - 1)] = "someValue";` doesn't give you an exception then it means the array of size actually increased. Your initial size was 0. That line would have given you `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` otherwise.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

Comment: That's exactly how it is implemented in my code but yet it still won't work. What could be the reason?

Comment: See my updated answer. Array size actually increased